# How to place a treeview in a UWP combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, treeview

I have hierarchical data that I wish to display as a tree, from within a UWP combobox.

How can I change the display of the combobox to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own combobox to achieve that. If there not many layers of hierarchy, you could place a Label as combobox items and change the font properties such as italic or bold. But that is simple and not fancy.